# Applying grouped ranking using ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I m Looking for ways to assign the row numbers as below for the table

```
Roll No    Name    Score 
 1           ABC    10
 1           ABC    10
 1           DEF     8
 2           ASC     9
 2           YHN     4
 3           IOP     5
 3           YHN     4
```

I m looking for a way to assign the roll no as Rownumber()

```
Roll No    Name    Score    Row_Number
 1           ABC    10        1
 1           ABC    10        2
 1           DEF     8        3
 2           ASC     9        1
 2           YHN     4        2
 3           IOP     5        1 
 3           YHN     4        2
```

I m trying to work around with Row_number() , it is isnt working . ANy inputs on this world be great :)

Thanks !!!!

Comment: For future ref, it is usually extremely helpful to show what you've tried, and what "isn't working" means - e.g. wrong results, actual error message, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT [Roll No], Name, Score, [ROW_NUMBER] = 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Roll No] ORDER BY Score DESC)
FROM dbo.table
ORDER BY [Roll No], [ROW_NUMBER];
```

If you later decide that you want to handle ties in a different way, play with using `RANK()` or `DENSE_RANK()` in place of `ROW_NUMBER()`...